# Display Camera Intent Only In Webview in android?unable to get Camera Intent only?android 5+ and 6+

Tags: android, webview, camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

I followed [this](https://infeeds.com/d/CODEmgks/20475/upload-image-file-gallery-or-camera-webv) or [this](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp) to upload Images and capture upload Images form gallery or camera to web-view

I here its working in android 6+ but here I am getting Gallery or Filemanager not camera...

Can any one suggest me To get Camera Intent only(insted of gallery or filemanager).. To capture and upload in webview..

I am getting below options

[image]
I am not getting Camera Intent In webview..
It working fine in browser and Uploading Image but not in web-view please help...

**Update 1**

When I click on the Android System I am getting Camera

[image]

Is it possible to get that camera directly in web-view.. Please help in android 6+ I am not getting even Android system intent also.. there is no option to choose Camera....

But Same thing is working in browser.. Not in web-view

**Update 2**

By using the same in Emulator its showing Camera option only.. But Where as in Real Device Its showing file-manger or Gallery for android 6+ there is no Camera option
I tried with Almost all Brands Even Redmi and YU also

Here I tried with Custom Camera But over there I am unable to Upload Image Please Help

Plese any one suggest me Regarding this

Comment: Do you ask permission on Android 6.0?  Permissions have changed on Android M. Permissions are now requested at runtime.

Comment: Its not Permission problem I am also getting same problem on android 5+ and 6+ I have given all Run time and manifest permissions